# Nested if loop jumps to second if even when first isn't true

Tags: c++, arduino

I have a flex sensor wired up to an arduino board, and I'm trying to count the number of times the sensor has been bent back and forth.

I set up a nested if loop so that the sensor must be bent all the way closed then all the way the way open to increase the count, however it increments the count constantly when holding it open.

How do I get the count to increase only when the sensor has been bent first past handClosed then past handOpen?

```
#include <Servo.h>
Servo myServo;

const int flexPin = A0; 
const int ledPin = 7; 
bool closed = false;
int handOpenCount = 0;
int handClosed = 150;
int handOpen = 250;

void setup() 
{ 
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(ledPin,OUTPUT);
} 

void loop() 
{ 

  int flexValue;  
  flexValue = analogRead(flexPin);
  Serial.print("sensor: ");
  Serial.println(" ");
  Serial.println(flexValue);



  // Counts number of times hand has been open
  if(flexValue<handClosed){
    closed = true;}
  if(closed=true){
    if(flexValue>handOpen){
          handOpenCount = handOpenCount + 1;
          closed = false;}
Serial.println(handOpenCount);}
```

Comment: An `if` statement is not a loop; a loop means it does the same thing over and over, while the compiler reads the `if` statement wants, executes it (or not), and then continues on with the rest of the code. Presumably the function `loop()` is run in a loop of some sort which you don't show, but it contains no loops itself.

Comment: `if(closed=true)` ??? This is an assignment! If at all, you'd need `if(closed == true)`, but you shouldn't compare booleans that way at all! Instead (simply): `if(closed)`

Comment: @DanielH This is Arduino. On that platform, there's a `main` function provided (implicitly) that does more or less something like `setup(); for(;;) { /*possibly some platform specific tasks*/ loop(); /*possibly some other tasks*/ }`

Comment: @Aconcagua That counts as running `loop()` in a loop of some sort which isn't shown, and doesn't change my complaint about calling something in C an "if loop".

Comment: @DanielH Well, just that the actual loop is not exposed to the user (programmer) on that platform. It's what you need to know about if programming Arduino. I don't want to argue about if this was a good idea or not – just to state that on Arduino, `setup` and `loop` functions are replacing what we usually cover with `main` function (containing some endless loop).

Comment: @Aconcagua My point isn't about how the loop happens or even if there is a loop. My point is that the phrase "`if` loop", as used by the OP, looks like the phrases "`while` loop" and "`for` loop", implying that `if (cond) { true_branch(); } else { false_branch(); }` is itself a lopp the same way `while (cond) { body(); }` is, which is at best confusing terminology and at worst indicates a deeper misunderstanding of some sort.

Comment: @DanielH I see – agree on that...

Answer (score 1):

Your comparator for your if statement needs a second equals (==):

```
if(closed == true){
    if(flexValue>handOpen){
        handOpenCount = handOpenCount + 1;
        closed = false;}
}
```

Your current if statement will set closed to true and, in doing so, returns as true.

Comment: Technically correct – but booleans should simply be checked as `if(condition)` or, if inverse is intended, as `if(!condition)`.

Comment: @Aconcagua Is there a reason that is better? I'm genuinely curious because I may need to change my style :-) I tend to find that readability is better when the comparison is explicitly stated?

Comment: Hm, haven't found anyone with notable experience aggreeing on this statement so far... *'Is there a that is better?'* Thought that I showed up already? At least, naming of the variable might indicate more clearly that it is a boolean variable (I personally prefer `isClosed` or `hasWhatever` naming scheme for booleans).

Comment: IMO readabliity is a matter of taste. Any compiler will create the same code for both.
However, this post shows `if (test = true)` is error prone and causes c - compiler evil grin

Comment: @datafiddler Yeah, that was where I landed with it too. I had the same thought as you have with it being error prone, but they would run into the same error if it wasn't a Boolean & weren't into the habit of using `==`

Comment: Hm, we wouldn't discuss about `int x, y; /*...*/ if((x == y) == true) { }`, would we?